# displaying and sorting a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array.i need to get the item id check in the db and get the manufacturer.
after that I need to write every item to a HTML table where the tables are created for all manufacurers in the array. 
example
Items in these 3 arrays are made by two seperate manufacturers.
Now I need help with the code to dinamicly create table for each manufacturer and add the corresponding item in the table

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3 //item id
        [1] => 1 //quantity
        [2] =>  efg //some text
        [3] => 50 //price
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] =>  bla bla bla
        [3] => 10
    )
```

[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
            [2] =>  abe
            [3] => 15
        )

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your data in the SQL query. [best]
2. [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), [`uasort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), [`uksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Comment: these arrays are from a session